# how to wrap questions and answers in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a poll application with java and jQuery for UI. The questions will be visible but answers will be hidden. I want that when a user clicks a question the answers will slide down. But in the implementation should i make every question and it's answers in a different 'div' element. What should be my outline?

Comment: Please note that *java* and *javascript* are two different things entirely ("java is to javascript what car is to carpet", as they say). you probably want to do this in *javascript*

Comment: yes, definetely in javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to solve the problem, but I'd do something like this:

```
<div class="question">
   Question
   <div class="answer" style="display: none;">
      Answer!
   </div>
</div>
```

And script-wise

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.question').click(function() {
       $(this).find('.answer').slideDown('fast');
   });
});
```

Comment: I would probably rather do `$('.answer', this)` than `$(this).find('.answer')`, but it's more a matter of taste than anything else.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: yes, that's probably preferable! there should be a slight overhead. i think they translate to the same, but yours is without the round-trip of wrapping `this` in `$`

Comment: @David: 
Should i create a div for every question? Because i will have more than 20 questions. and is it better to add id attribute for each div?

Comment: @yakup85: yes, one div for each question. and they should all have the same *class* so that the jQuery can find them all in one go. don't bother with ID, because ID has to be unique for each element. regardless of how many copies you make of HTML like the one I've posted above, you don't have to change a bit in the jQuery script for it to work on all questions.

Comment: @David: I would guess, although I haven't looked at the source code, that `jQuery.find()` just returns what I did. However, you don't need to wrap `this` in `$` either - it is already a wrapped set, only Visual Studio can't see that if you don't wrap it. So `this.find('.answer')` is perfectly fine - and for less than thousands of questions, I doubt that there's really a perf hit.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: yeah, it won't be measurable =) i think you're wrong about `this` though. in an event listener, the context is the DOM node, not pre-wrapped in `$`. So `$('div').click(function() { console.log(typeof this.find); });` logs `undefined`.